# XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, format, serialization

I have tried to use the xsd.exe tool to generate a class for the 
following Oracle-generated xml sample but always fail to get it right 
when I try to change oracle xml elements names to the class's names, 
specifically I'm not sure how to do it for the ROWSET and ROW part of 
it.

Being very new to the serialization/deserialization business I'm sure 
this is very easy to implement for someone with a bit of more 
knowledge of it, can some help me please.

I have created 2 classes for for Department and Employee:

```
[XmlRoot("ROWSET")] 
class Department 
{ 
    [XmlElement("DEPARTMENT_ID")] 
    string DepID { set; get; } 
    [XmlElement("DEPARTMENT_NAME")] 
    string DepName { set; get; } 
    [XmlElement("EMPLOYEES")] 
    Employee[] Employees { set; get; } 
} 
class Employee 
{ 
    [XmlElement("EMP_ID")] 
    string DepID { set; get; } 
    [XmlElement("EMP_NAME")] 
    string DepName { set; get; } 
}
```

But this fails to work, on runtime it complains it cannot find the ROW 
element, which to be honest I don't know how to tell in the code to 
ignore it and start with the next node. I know xsd.exe would help me but it generates lots of unwanted data plus leaves me to sort the names manually. I would 
really like to learn how to do this without relying on an automation 
tool.

Many thanks,

Maya

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <DEPARTMENT_ID>1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
    <DEPARTMENT_NAME>Sales</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
    <EMPLOYEES>
      <EMP>
        <EMP_ID>12</EMP_ID>
        <EMP_NAME>Fred</EMP_NAME>
      </EMP>
      <EMP>
        <EMP_ID>13</EMP_ID>
        <EMP_NAME>Hohn</EMP_NAME>
      </EMP>
    </EMPLOYEES>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <DEPARTMENT_ID>2</DEPARTMENT_ID>
    <DEPARTMENT_NAME>Marketing</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
    <EMPLOYEES></EMPLOYEES>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: You'll need to declare a class that can store a collection of Departments.  Check out XmlArrayAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create an additional class `Row`. Also make sure classes and properties are public. Here's an example of how to serialize a `Department` instance to the given XML structure using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

```
[XmlRoot("ROWSET")]
public class Department
{
    [XmlElement("ROW")]
    public Row[] Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlElement("DEPARTMENT_ID")]
    public string DepID { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("DEPARTMENT_NAME")]
    public string DepName { set; get; }

    [XmlArray("EMPLOYEES")]
    [XmlArrayItem("EMP")]
    public Employee[] Employees { set; get; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [XmlElement("EMP_ID")]
    public string EmpID { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("EMP_NAME")]
    public string EmpName { set; get; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dep = new Department
        {
            Rows = new[] 
            {
                new Row 
                {
                    DepID = "1",
                    DepName = "Sales",
                    Employees = new[] 
                    {
                        new Employee 
                        {
                            EmpID = "12",
                            EmpName = "Fred"
                        },
                        new Employee 
                        {
                            EmpID = "13",
                            EmpName = "Hohn"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Row 
                {
                    DepID = "2",
                    DepName = "Marketing",
                }
            }
        };
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dep.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, dep);
    }
```

And to deserialize back to a `Department` instance:

```
var xml = 
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <DEPARTMENT_ID>1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
    <DEPARTMENT_NAME>Sales</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
    <EMPLOYEES>
      <EMP>
        <EMP_ID>12</EMP_ID>
        <EMP_NAME>Fred</EMP_NAME>
      </EMP>
      <EMP>
        <EMP_ID>13</EMP_ID>
        <EMP_NAME>Hohn</EMP_NAME>
      </EMP>
    </EMPLOYEES>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <DEPARTMENT_ID>2</DEPARTMENT_ID>
    <DEPARTMENT_NAME>Marketing</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
    <EMPLOYEES></EMPLOYEES>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>";

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var department = (Department)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```